# Powershell - alias for a running a multiple background commands

Tags: git, powershell

I have a directory with 10 `git` repos.
I would like to do `git pull` on all of them, in parallel, in a single command:

```
gpa // git-pull-all
```

This should actually do the following:

```
cd c:\repos;
foreach $dir in `ls -d` do
    git pull & // unix version for background
    cd ..
end
```

This should be quite simple in `bash` (unix). In powershell I find it very complicated.
How can I do it properly?

Comment: `PS C:\> help about_Jobs`

Answer (score 2):

This would not be an alias (in PowerShell parlance), it would just be a function or a script.

Mostly you would just find the relevant analogues in PowerShell.

So `ls` in PowerShell is actually an alias for `Get-ChildItem`, which in PowerShell v3+ also supports a `-Directory` parameter to return only directories, so that part almost works right away.

Although you can do a `foreach($thing in $things)` loop, in this case it would be a bit more natural (PowerShell-ey) to pipe into `ForEach-Object`, so something like this:

```
$repos = 'C:\repos'
Get-ChildItem -Path $repos -Directory | ForEach-Object -Process {
    Push-Location -Path $_
    git pull
    Pop-Location
}
```

For reference, using aliases and alternate syntax to make it look the most like your original, it could be done like this:

```
cd c:\repos
foreach ($dir in (ls -di)) {
    git pull
    cd ..
}
```

However I recommend the first one because:

- it preserves your original path
- it doesn't use aliases
- it uses what I feel is a more straightforward way of iterating (in PowerShell)

Neither of these examples handle the backgrounding of the task though. I left that out for the time being because it's not as analogous.

To do that you can use [PowerShell Jobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_jobs). Either with `Start-Job` or with `Invoke-Command -AsJob`.

Have a look at how to use jobs and decide if you want to spend the time to apply it for just 10 repos though.